# Stoyan Stefanov: JavaScript Patterns - Callbacks and Scope

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, callback, this

In chapter 4 (Functions) in the section "Callbacks and Scope" you can find the following example:

```
var myapp = {};
myapp.color = "green";
myapp.paint = function (node) {
    node.style.color = this.color;
};

var findNodes = function (callback) {
    // ...
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        callback(found);
    }
    // ...
};
```

In my version of this (e-)book, the author wrote:

"If you call findNodes(myapp.paint), it won’t work as expected, because this.color will not be defined. The object this will refer to the global object because findNodes() is invoked as a function, not as a method. If findNodes() was defined as a method of an object called dom (like dom.findNodes()), then this inside of the callback would refer to dom instead of the expected myapp."

I don't understand this explanation. Perhaps the author were wrong?

In my opinion, the argumentation is misleading. If findeNotes() is invoked as a method or invoked as a function is irrelevant for the this-value in the method myapp.paint(). In either case the this-value will be refer to the global object, because it is determined by the form of the invocation "callback(found)" (See http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/#this-value).

Can anyone please help me to find the right answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thoughts are correct. `this` inside `findNodes` would be either the global object or another object, but `this` inside `callback` will always be the global object.

One way to remedy it would be:

```
var findNodes = function (callback) {
    // ...
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        callback.call(this,found); // CHANGED HERE
    }
    // ...
};
```

This way the scope of findNodes would be passed to the callback. That would at least make the author correct.

The more common way to deal with callbacks is to provide an optional parameter that defines the scope:

```
var findNodes = function (callback, scope) {
    // ...
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        callback.call(scope,found); // CHANGED HERE
    }
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The author is wrong. He probably misused `findNodes` for `paint` in explanation.

- calling myapp.paint() binds this to myapp object
- calling var func = myapp.paint; func() binds this to global window object.

Corrected explanation could look like this

> If you call findNodes(myapp.paint), it won’t work as expected,
>   because this.color will not be defined. The object this will refer to
>   the global object because **paint**() is invoked as a function, not as a
>   method. If **paint**() was defined as a method of an object called dom
>   (like dom.**paint**()), then this inside of the callback would refer to
>   dom instead of the expected myapp.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried also to "repair" the argumentation of the author. Your corrected explanation makes more sense for me except for the last sentence. Why should be paint() a method of dom?

Comment: Yeah that didn't make sense to me either.  @Tibos answer is more accurate.